# How to enter data when JFrame form is minimized in Java?

Tags: java, swing, barcode-scanner, jlist, minimize

How to get barcode details to a list when the JFrame form is minimized. I am trying to get each barcode details to a JList when the form is minimized. I am using this code to seperate barcode details from other key events. But I can't figure out how to put details to a JList when even the JFrame is minimized.

So How can I fix it? Anyone can help me?
Thanks for the help in advance! Best Regards.

```
private static final long THRESHOLD = 100;
private static final int MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH = 8;
private final StringBuffer barcode = new StringBuffer();
private long lastEventTimeStamp = 0L;
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();

KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getID() != KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (e.getWhen() - lastEventTimeStamp > THRESHOLD)
                {
                    barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                }

                lastEventTimeStamp = e.getWhen();

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    if (barcode.length() >= MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH)
                    {
                        jList1.setModel(dlm);
                        dlm.addElement(barcode.toString().trim());
                    }
                    barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                } else {
                    barcode.append(e.getKeyChar());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Any window which is minimised isn't going to get keyboard focus, so it's unlikely to be notified of possible key events.  Not sure why you're trying to perform this in this manner, typically you have a field which has keyboard focus, into which the result of the scan can be captured

Comment: Your JList should be a view over the model, not the model itself. So as already noted, the focus will not be on the containing frame.